# Unused variable vs let () and let _?

Tags: ocaml

Let's say I have a bunch of nested let...in statements. I noticed that if I have

```
(* a bunch of let... in above *)
let test = expr1 in
(* a bunch of let ... in below *)
```

I get this `Error (warning 26): unused variable test`, yet when I change it to `let _ = expr1 in ...` or `let () = expr1 in ...` there are no error messages.

I understand `let _ =`  is pattern matching for anything and `let () =` is pattern matching for anything of type unit, but does this mean that my `expr1` is just being executed anywhere? Is it being called once?

Comment: Yes, `expr1` is executed normally, regardless how you treat its result

Comment: @Bergi Is the difference that if you give expr1 a name, it won't be executed unless the name is 'called' somewhere later on?

Comment: No, OCaml doesn't do lazy evaluation. There is no difference between the two ways in that regard.

Comment: Cross-posted to https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/unused-variable-vs-let-and-let/9081/3

Comment: Also worth mentioning: the standard library has a function called `ignore`, that you can use like this: `ignore expr1 ; …`; then `expr1` is executed and its result discarded, just as if you had written `let _ = expr1 in …` The function is defined as `let ignore _ = ()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a very simple experiment you can do do test this:

```
let test = print_endline "named";;
let _ = print_endline "any pattern";;
let () = print_endline "unit";;
```

As you can see, whether you put this in a source file and compile it or run it in the toplevel, it will print each string exactly once.

OCaml is a strictly evaluated (more specifically, call by value) language with side-effects, which means it will evaluate expressions in order, and not optimize away code with potential side-effects.

Comment: Thanks, is there any difference in meaning between separating everything with ;; vs ;?  I've read that ; is similar to "in"

Comment: Yes, `;` is a sequence operator, used to sequence expressions. `;;` is used to terminate toplevel definitions, and is really only needed in the toplevel (REPL) to signal that you've completed the definition, and to evaluate it. It isn't really needed here, except for the last one if you enter this into the toplevel. Outside the toplevel you don't ever need to use it.